# How do I output a visual to the screen using C++?

Tags: c++, graphics

I am a Computer Science student working on a project, and I need some help.  I'm writing this in C++.  In my project, I basically need some way to output a graphic to the screen.  It doesn't have to be pretty at all, but I don't know how to do it.  If there are any libraries that would be helpful I could use them, but I don't know what they are.

Basically I am writing a program in which an object can be moved around in space.  It will have a starting point, and an ending point, and I want to be able to output its path as it moves along it, so that the user can actually watch the object moving around in space.  I've thought about trying something with ray tracing, but I don't think that's quite what I'm looking for.  Like I said, it doesn't have to be pretty.  A dot moving to another dot would be good enough, I just need to have something.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would be helpful if you stated your target OS and desktop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I build a GUI in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186017/how-do-i-build-a-gui-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

In [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610210/c-graphic-drawing-library), they suggest using Cairo. I used it in the past for creating a pdf to animate (page by page), but it seems it can display directly to screen as well integrating with OpenGL.